Infant son's name on Schengen tourist visa (Switzerland) differs from passport
My infant son's name on his Schengen tourist visa (Switzerland) is printed differently from his passport. His name is Nityam Dwij Mehta. His mother's name is Jalpa Lakha Hun, and my name is Dwij Nitinbhai Mehta. In his visa, his name is written as Nityam Dwij Hun.
What do I do now?

What did the VAC / embassy that issued the visa say when you contacted them?

I have not contacted them yet. I have received Visa today only

I’m voting to close this question because the only possible answer is to contact the issuer.

Does the passport number on the visa match that of the passport?

It both are on the same passport, it is clear that both refers to the same person. Do not put much stress on names on visas: different conventions (and transliteration).

If you have time to get the visa corrected, you should probably do that.  There should be no charge.  If you do not have time, then you have little choice but to travel with the visa as it was issued.  You might have some trouble, but I suspect you'll be able to talk your way through it by stressing that the passport number on the visa is correct, as suggested in Mark Johnson's answer.

Probably not the best idea to reveal so much personal information in the post. Just letting us know that the surnames of the parents are swapped on the passport and visa adequately conveys the same information

A Schengen visa is issued against a valid travel document.
The number of the travel document (in most cases a passport) will also be printed on the visa sticker that will be affixed to the travel document.
Therefore it is important that the passport number on the visa sticker matches that of the passport.

Now what to do?

Check if the passport number on the visa sticker matches that of the passport:

if yes:

nothing needs to be done


if no:

report this to the issuing consulate




I have downvoted this answer as it is unsourced and my sense is that it is quite likely that "nothing needs to be done" is extremely risky advice

Downvoted: Every time I applied for a visa for schengen countries I was given a slip of paper saying that if any of my information on visa is incorrect, I should contact the embassy immediately.
